Bound on $\int_0^1\sqrt{\log N_{[]}(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},d)} \, d\varepsilon$ over the class of half-spaces $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$?
For a class of functions $\mathcal{F}$ and a pair $f,g\in\mathcal{F}$ with $f\leq g$, the interval $[f,g]=\{h:f(x)\leq h(x)\leq g(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^d\}$ is called a bracket for $\mathcal{F}$. If $d$ is a metric on $\mathcal{F}$, then de bracketing number $N_{[]}(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},d)$ is the minimal number of brackets $[f,g]$ needed to cover $\mathcal{F}$ such that $d(f,g)\leq\varepsilon$.
Now if $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of all (indicators of) half-spaces over $\mathbb{R}^d$, i.e., all sets of the form
$$
H(u,v)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^d:v^\top(y-u)\geq 0\}
$$
where $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^d$.
Question: Does this class (the half-spaces) satisfy the integral condition
$$
\int_0^1\sqrt{\log N_{[]}(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},d)} \, d\varepsilon<\infty
$$
where $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|_p$ denotes the $L^p$-norm (for simplicity, $p$ can be taken 1 or 2)? Here, the underlying probability measure can be assumed to be Lebesgue absolutely continuous. Note also that this integral is nothing but the Dudley entropy integral where we changed $N$ to $N_{[]}$.
Here are some known facts that might help to answer the question:
It is well known that the collection $\mathcal{F}$ is bracketing compact, meaning that $N_{[]}(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},d)<\infty$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. Furthermore, the collectoin $\mathcal{F}$ is totally bounded, with envelope $F$ satisfying $|F|\leq 1$. Additionally, the class $\mathcal{F}$ is a VC-class of dimension $d+2$ and the entropy number $N$ satisfies
$$
N(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_{r})\leq K(d+2)(4e)^{d+2}\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)^{r(d+2)},
$$
see theorem 2.6.4 in the book weak convergence and empirical processes. Additionally, it is known that $N(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_{L^r})\leq N_{[]}(2\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_{L^r})$ for $r\geq 1$, yet I do not know whether one can bound $N_{[]}$ in terms of $N$ (or the VC dimension) if $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies various properties. A notable exception is when we consider the uniform norm, i.e., $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, from which we obtain the equality
$$
N(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_{\infty})=N_{[]}(2\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_{\infty}),
$$
see page 132 in the above book for a proof.
I also asked this question on math.stackexchange, yet I figured perhaps it is better suited to be asked on math overflow.
Any help is welcome!

I am confused how $\mathcal{F}$ is bracketing compact. For $f,g \in mathcal{F}$, in order to have $f\leq g$ everywhere, we need both of them to be in the exactly same direction, and then the bracket $[f,g]$ covers only (some) subspaces in that direction. So finite number number of brackets covers only finite number of directions. What am I missing?

@JarosławBłasiok, given that $Q$ is a probability measure, we can simply take a compact $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $Q(\mathbb{R}^d\setminus A)\leq\delta$ and then apply brackets. I am not sure precisely how these brackets will come to play, but I am fairly sure that the bracketing compactness of $\mathcal{F}$ under $Q$ remains valid.

I still don't understand how is $\mathcal{F}$ supposed to be bracketing-compact under $Q$, according to definitions in the OP. Let's even take it for granted that whenever $Q$ is compactly supported, and we change the partial order on $\mathcal{F}$ to $f\leq g$ iff $\Pr_{x \sim Q}(f(x) \leq g(x)) = 1$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is bracketing compact (also changing the notion of $[f,g]$ accordingly).  I don't see how would that imply that $\mathcal{F}$ is bracketing compact with definitions from OP. Why would intersecting with a compact $A$ help? What to do with remaining $\delta$ mass?
